# SQL reformat row to column

Tags: sql, reformat

Hi I have a table like:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
v1 xx xx a  1
v1 xx xx b  2
v2 xx xx a  3
v3 xx xx a  2
v3 xx xx b  1
```

I want to remove c4 and transfer c5 into 2 column based on c4 value:

```
c1 c2 c3 c5_a c5_b
v1 xx xx  1     2
v2 xx xx  3     0
v3 xx xx  2     1
```

How do I do this in SQL?

Comment: _How do I do this in SQL?_ What have you tried so far to do in sql?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slight tweak on vkp's answer, but it is a bit simpler:

```
select c1, c2, c3,
       max(case when c4 = 'a' then c5 else 0 end) as c5_a,
       max(case when c4 = 'b' then c5 else 0 end) as c5_b
from t
group by c1, c2, c3;
```

Also, it is unclear whether you want `max()` or `sum()`.

Note:  This assumes that the `xx` values are the same in each row.  Otherwise, you might need aggregation functions on those as well:

```
select c1, max(c2) as c2, max(c3) as c3,
       max(case when c4 = 'a' then c5 else 0 end) as c5_a,
       max(case when c4 = 'b' then c5 else 0 end) as c5_b
from t
group by c1;
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right I wanted the sum(). So the sum will based on the filter on c4 and do sum on c5? I also not clear why you removed the coalesce function but still get the same result? @Gordon Linoof

Comment: @KarlTMuahahaT . . . The `else 0` makes up for the lack of `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with conditional aggregation, assuming the grouping columns are c1,c2,c3.

```
select c1,c2,c3,
coalesce(max(case when c4='a' then c5 end),0) as c5_a,
coalesce(max(case when c4='b' then c5 end),0) as c5_b
from t
group by c1,c2,c3
```